# Jenkins declarative pipeline upon Bitbucket pull request

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am building a declarative pipeline Jenkinsfile for semantic branching. It has the format:

```
pipeline {
  stages {
    stage('develop branch build') {
      when {
        branch 'develop'
      }

      // build and deploy to QA environment
    }

    stage('release branch build') {
      when {
        branch 'release'
      }

      // build and deploy to live/preproduction environment
    }
  }
}
```

I would like an additional stage to run upon a Bitbucket pull request. It would do a particular PR test and deploy task, and pass or fail the pipeline accordingly.

How might I enhance this script to do that?

Comment: You could block off the stage with an input parameter boolean that is set to `true` in the webhook from the Bitbucket PR. Not sure if that is best practices or not, but it works.

Comment: @funkybro if you install the Bitbucket source plugin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60711551/jenkins-pipeline-determine-if-a-branch-is-for-bitbucket-pull-request

Answer (score 1):

I use the generic webhook plugin. This work pretty nice with bitbucket.