# Jenkins pipeline determine if a branch is for Bitbucket pull request

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, devops

I'm using Jenkins together with the [Bitbucket branch source plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/bitbucket-branch-source-plugin/blob/master/docs/USER_GUIDE.adoc).

Everything works great, but I want to be able to run/exclude certain stages in my pipeline depending on whether the branch is associated with a pull request or not, such as:

```
pipeline {
  stages {
    stage('build') {
      //compile
    }    
    stage('package') {
      when {
        environment name: 'IS_PULL_REQUEST', value: 'true'
      }      
      //create deployable package
    }
  }
}
```

Jenkins knows when the branch is for a PR because it merges the source with the target and also displays the branch in the pull request folder on the multibranch pipeline page.

Is there an environment variable I can use within the pipeline to exclude/include stages?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `BRANCH_NAME` and `CHANGE_ID` environment variables to detect pull requests. When you run a multibranch pipeline build from a branch (before creating a pull request), the following environment variables are set:

- `env.BRANCH_NAME` is set to the repository branch name (e.g. `develop`),
- `env.CHANGE_BRANCH` is `null`,
- `env.CHANGE_ID` is `null`.

But once you create a pull request, then:

- `env.BRANCH_NAME` is set to the PR-\d+ name (e.g. `PR-11`),
- `env.CHANGE_BRANCH` is set to the real branch name (e.g. `develop`),
- `env.CHANGE_ID` is set to the pull request ID (e.g. `11`).

I use the following `when` condition in my pipelines to detect pull requests:

```groovy
when {
    expression {
        // True for pull requests, false otherwise.
        env.CHANGE_ID && env.BRANCH_NAME.startsWith("PR-")
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are these variables defined? I mean, what plugin is responsible of injecting them? Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

In Declarative Pipelines, you can also use the built-in condition `changeRequest` inside the `when` directive to determine if the branch is associated with a pull request.

```
stage('package') {
  when {
    changeRequest()
  }      
  //create deployable package
}
```

You can also check if the pull request is targeted at a particular branch:

```
stage('package') {
  when {
    changeRequest target: 'master'
  }      
  //create deployable package
}
```

See https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when.