# How to automatically triggers Jenkins job when there is a Git tag push to Bitbucket server

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket-server, git-tag

I am not able to figure out how to automatically triggers Jenkins job when there is a Git tag push to Bitbucket server using multibranch pipeline. I can manually trigger it but automatic trigger isn't working when there is a new tag push to the remote repo

Comment: Check the answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/73438320/2627018

Comment: Thanks, but this seems not to help.