# Is there a way to automatically re-trigger Jenkins pipeline when the PR state changes from draft to redy to review?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a multi-branch pipeline. My pipeline gets triggered automatically when a PR is created. However, we have different default parameters fro PR and draft PRs. Therefore, I would like to automatically trigger a pipeline whenever the state of the pipeline changes from Draft to Open/ready for review. This is currently a manual process.

Comment: Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73438320/2627018

Comment: @ycr thank you. It looks bit like a hack. I am really surprised that there is no native way to do it in git plugin in jenkins.